# CodenameOne database retention

Tags: sqlite, codenameone

I have a problem (bug) with the database in my CodenameOne application. Sometimes, after the update from PlayStore/App store, the database becomes empty, as if no data were saved in it. The data just gets scrubbed. User cannot do that, so maybe its something connected to sqlite. Any suggestions/ideas why that happens are welcome.

Comment: With this given information, it's difficult for others to give a suggestion. Please add some more details

Comment: I submitted an answer assuming this wasn't sqlite but then I saw the sqlite tag. I haven't run into such an issue where a database is wiped or missing on upgrade. My only suggestion is to do a lot of logging in your app and try to code defensively to find out what might happen. If it happens in both appstore & play store I think this might relate to program logic as the implementations on our side are very different.